# 2D Java array- how to input values

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am a 1st year student, and I don't know what to do here.  I have input values but I keep getting 0 as a result.  I am expecting output like this:

```
0000000000

1111111111

2222222222

3333333333

4444444444
```

but it keeps on giving me 0.

Here is my code so far:

```
    String [][]array2D = new String[5][10];

    for(int r=0; r<array2D.length; r++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<array2D[r].length; b++)
        {
            System.out.print(array2D[r][b]);    
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Prepared By: Mark Vincent D. Yap");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the desired result:

```
    String [][]array2D = new String[5][10];

    for(int r=0; r<array2D.length; r++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<array2D[r].length; b++)
        {
            array2D[r][b] = Integer.toString(r);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int r=0; r<array2D.length; r++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<array2D[r].length; b++)
        {
            System.out.print(array2D[r][b]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Prepared By: Diligent Key Presser");
```

Hope you will take advance of this, not just copy and paste.

Comment: thank you so much sir @Diligent Key Presser ^^ i have to cram for finals ^^ so i am in kinda rush

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to put inputs (filling array values) in your., rest of fine. See below is your code in which I just added array value input statement.

String [][]array2D = new String[5][10];

```
for(int r=0; r<array2D.length; r++)
{
    for(int b=0; b<array2D[r].length; b++)
    {
        array2d[r][b]=String.values(r);  
        System.out.print(array2D[r][b]);    
    }
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("Prepared By: Mark Vincent D. Yap");
```

}